# nodejs PM2 cluster mode for load balancing

Tags: node.js, pm2

When using pm2 cluster there's a pretty severe warning saying you shouldn't use it in production, nor for load balancing, use nginx instead. Unfortunately that's exactly how I planned to use PM2. Is it really not intended to be used for that purpose or is it just not completely ready yet?

Answer (score 1):

The nodejs cluster (0.10) has a lot of issues and is not safe to use in production!
You may want to give a try with 0.11, there were some improvements.

This feature has not anything to do with pm2, it's in fact directly related to [node cluster module](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html).

Comment: I'm using the pm2 -i flag which uses cluster? I don't get the error when using cluster manually only through PM2.

Comment: I use .10 Where is the documentation for fork mode? If I use .11 then I wouldn't get this error? Thanks.

Comment: Indeed using node 0.11.x will bypass the error. [PM2 docs](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/blob/master/ADVANCED_README.md#execute-any-kind-of-script).